# Windows Home Server vs Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-home-server

i am a home user of windows 7 and really like the new features like

- jumplists
- taskbar thumbnails etc

i am also exploring benefits of homegroup, federated search and since i am a developer intending to start ASP.NET MVC 2 development from PHP, i am thinking a Windows Home Server maybe useful for me.

but what i need, IIS, homegroups etc are offered in Windows 7 too. i am wondering why will i want to have a home server instead? i believe it will offer some benefits i should know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Home Server is based on Windows Server 2003 SP2.

[Public beta of new Windows Home Server](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/windowshomeserver/archive/2010/04/26/wanna-peek-at-the-next-version-of-windows-home-server-check-out-the-new-public-beta-for-windows-home-server-code-name-vail.aspx)

Best way for you is Windows 7, because they support latest IIS (webserver). Or wait to next version of WHS.

Comment: if i get a home server i will definitely wait for WHS "vail". i have actually looked at Acer EasyStore wonder hows it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Home Server really is designed to be (but doesn't have to be) headless, for people with multiple computers wanting to backup multiple computers, have a central file store and more.

It can be used as a regular machine (as it is based on Windows Server) but I really would not recommend it.

If you are not actually going to be hosting but just developing, I recommend you use [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/web/) (Or full Visual Studio). It includes Cassini/ASP.Net Development Server which is basically a very light-weight server for hosting ASP.NET applications.

Alternatively, you can install [Microsoft Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx) and then install Windows Server on top of that which gives you the best of both worlds.